# Cómo puedo hacer que el botón de borrado elimine la cadena escrita en el input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando una web y querría poner en todas las distintas páginas que la componen un búscador (el cual está arriba a la derecha en la barra de navegación ya implementado junto al botón que debería borrar el contenido introducido en el input) pero tras haber creado el script que se encargaría de eliminarlo, este botón de borrado no funciona. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo funcionar?

Por ahora tengo lo desarrollado en este enlace:
https://codepen.io/diegomanzanares/pen/rNdKZxr

Comment: Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas, es decir, deben contener todo el código necesario que nos permita reproducir tu error.  Los enlaces externos al código se pierden con el tiempo y entonces la pregunta y sus respuestas pierden el sentido, por eso no estan bien aceptados por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holap, antes de ejecutar jQuery debes hacer el link en el head de tu archivo index.html

Añadiendo lo siguiente :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El head quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" /><title>Contacto - Mixi</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger chat-title="Mixi" agent-id="41fe496c-6e3a-4316-aa5a-05dae8cd911d" language-code="es"></df-messenger>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-229317979-1"></script>
<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'UA-229317979-1');</script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d48f664aec.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="preload" href="css/contact.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Ahora si está funcionando, muchas gracias!